How to set the time interval between SIGTERM and SIGKILL for a user process during Ubuntu 20.04 system shutdown
This is the source code of TestShutdown program:
bool stop = false;
void sig_handler(int signal)
{
    printf("receive signal %d\n", signal);
    fflush(stdout);
    fsync(fileno(stdout));
    stop = true;
}

int main()
{
    printf("start\n");
    signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);

    while (!stop) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        printf("waiting SIGTERM or SIGINT\n");
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(4000));
    printf("stop\n");
    return 0;
}

On my Ubuntu 20.04 system, I run the TestShutdown program in the terminal,  redirecting the output to a log file, then I run shutdown -r +0 in another terminal.
My expectation: after I run shutdown -r +0, the system waits at least 4s for TestShutdown to exit normally before restarting.
What happens: after I run shutdown -r +0, the system restarts very quickly, without waiting for TestShutdown to exit normally, and TestShutdown receives SIGTERM.
I have modified /etc/systemd/system.conf to set DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s and run sudo systemctl daemon-reload, but it doesn't work.
What should I do next?
